# Nginx returning 499

Tags: linux, http, ssl, nginx

I got nginx v1.6.2 installed on my linux server (Ubuntu 13.04) with ssl certificates from LetsEncrypt. It has been working great serving 5 domains with ssl encryption for over 3 months now, but all of a sudden I'm getting:

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

When i open some of my pages in a browser. However one site is still working without any problems. I did not change any of my nginx configs in the last 3 months but this still happened.

My nginx configuration is quite long so im putting it in a pastie
(Note this is only one of the configuration files, but all the others are identical except for the document root and the server name)
http://pastie.org/private/uw8asi6jrcz1qut97tnkq

The nginx error log is completly empty and so is the access log.
I did enable the logging in the configuration but it just wont give me any information.

I did however see that it is returning HTTP 499 which is:

```
A non-standard status code introduced by nginx for the case when a 
client closes the connection while nginx is processing the request
```

The Certificates are valid/renewed

I also already reinstalled nginx and restarted it a couple of times

And also googling this problem hasn't helped me either, because all of the articles about this error are just about forgetting the **ssl** in the **listen** section

Like this:

```
server {
    listen 443;
```

But as you can take it from configuration that is not the case.
Also it is not a client timeout because i tried it on so many different clients/browsers and even curl and wget. And i didnt even change anything before this started occurring

I Already looked at the communication in Wireshark and basically what I say is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLj4E.jpg

2. Column Source IP (if it starts with 31 its the server otherwise its the client)
3. Column Destination IP (same goes here)

(I just didnt want to include my IP Address)

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the resolv.conf file and replace the nameserver with google's public DNS 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 i.e.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

You can edit the file from terminal with the following line

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Or the second way is to change the DNS from your network settings.